# Creating a 3d graph using VivaGraphJS and using a particle system

Tags: graph, three.js

I'm trying to create a force directed graph layout with the data of nodes and edges I have.I want to use [VivaGRaphJS](https://github.com/anvaka/VivaGraphJS)  for this. I want to integrate it into a particle cloud in ThreeJS. I know how to do them individually, but i'm lost when it comes to using them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [ngraph.pixel](https://github.com/anvaka/ngraph.pixel), which combines `three.js` renderer with 3d layout engine from `ngraph` family. See [more demos here](https://github.com/anvaka/ngraph.pixel#demo).

Both VivaGraph and ngraph.pixel are sharing the same primitive structures.

Answer (score 0):

What you would need to do is to mix the three.js render loop with the VivaGraphJS render loop. But it doesnt look like VivaGraphJS exposes the simulation step. If it did, you could just grab the (x,y) coords of your nodes and pass them to your three.js particle cloud.

Also, did you look at the WebGL option of VivaGraphJS?

Comment: This link shows a way to get the node positions , I think i'll try the way you suggested using it .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302066/how-do-i-get-or-set-x-y-position-of-node?rq=1   .I need to use Threejs for the project i'm working on.

Comment: getting the node positions at the end of the simulation is the easy part. if you want to see the simulation running then you would need to dissect the  `renderer.run();` call.